# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PropertiesController#new - Couldn't find Property with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the other solutions worked for me. I have created a scaffold called Properties and have not changed any of the code for it, when I click on the automatically generated link to create a new property, it throws the error message in the title, specifically targeting my def set_property in my properties_controller. I have already created a default scaffold for Users which worked perfectly, which is why I am very confused.

I am on rails v 5.0.2 and ruby v 2.3.3

My Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'
  get 'users/about'

  resources :users
  resources :properties

  get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end

  root 'users#home'
end
```

My properties_controller.rb

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :new]

  # GET /properties
  # GET /properties.json
  def index
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  # GET /properties/1
  # GET /properties/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /properties/new
  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  # GET /properties/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /properties
  # POST /properties.json
  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /properties/1
  # PATCH/PUT /properties/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.update(property_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /properties/1
  # DELETE /properties/1.json
  def destroy
    @property.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to properties_url, notice: 'Property was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_property
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:name, :price, :bed, :bath, :car, :inspect)
    end
end
```

The link I press to get the message:

```
<%= link_to 'New Property', new_property_path %>
```

New property page:

```
  <h1>New Property</h1>

  <%= render 'form', property: @property %>

  <%= link_to 'Back', properties_path %>
```

and the form that this page renders:

```
    <%= form_for(property) do |f| %>
      <% if property.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(property.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this property from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% property.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :price %>
        <%= f.number_field :price %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :bed %>
        <%= f.number_field :bed %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :bath %>
        <%= f.number_field :bath %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :car %>
        <%= f.number_field :car %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :inspect %>
        <%= f.text_field :inspect %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Welcome! put brief code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `:new` from `before_action :set_property`:

```
before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

`set_property` searches for an `id` attribute in the `params` hash and then sets the `@property` with the *property* (record from the db) that matches that `id`, but with `new` you don't want to search for an existing *property*, you are creating a new one. So thats why `new` method sets `@property` with `Property.new`:

```
# GET /properties/new
def new
  @property = Property.new
end
```

Comment: Then I get: ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in PropertiesController#new - inspect is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.

Comment: @NathanMarshall That error is because you have an attribute named `inspect` and that word is defined by ActiveRecord, that is, you can't use it. Change that name and you will be fine.

Comment: Ah thanks heaps, worked perfectly! I am pretty new to rails so it is all a bit overwhelming right now.